# CPU is running significantly hotter after installing gfx driver and using Ubuntu 3D

Tags: 12.04

I have an HP 17" laptop with an ATI graphics card. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

A while ago I noticed that Ubuntu is running in 2D mode and I didn't like that so after some research I stumbled upon this https://askubuntu.com/a/252040/74345 and followed the exact steps to fix things. Everything went fine and I'm using 3D mode now.

However, after the restart I noticed my CPU is significantly hotter. Before the changes I made the temp never passed 50 degrees and after the update it's never getting below 70 degrees -_-.

Is this a known thing? What's happening exactly? At least where do I start my investigation?

Is it possible that it's using the CPU for the animations insdead of the GPU?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just how ATI GPUs work; they run hot.  You can lower the performance setting to help some though:

```
sudo -s
echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile
exit
```

You can use mid instead of low for a more balanced setting.

Comment: well it's the CPU that is running hot, not the GPU. But I'm not sure if they affect each other. Under windows, for example, the temp of the CPU never goes above 45 unless I'm doing some heavy work or playing games. 

I also tried different profiles, all the same. There is no load on the CPU whatsoever, it's just .. hot.

Comment: @Ali, the other thing you might try is adding "pcie_aspm=force" to your kernel command line arguments in /etc/default/grub and running `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I did that a minute ago but haven't restart yet, too scared :P.